# How do I pass "Log In via Twitter" credentials from a Rails back end to an iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, twitter, omniauth

I'm making the back end for an iOS app in Rails. Users need to be able to log into the app using an app-specific username/password or via Twitter, but I'm not quite sure how to set things up for logging in via Twitter.

If I use OmniAuth, then it seems like the flow goes like this:

1. The iOS app directs users, in Safari, to the /auth/twitter page OmniAuth sets up for me
2. The /auth/twitter page sends the user to Twitter for OAuth authentication
3. Twitter returns the user to /auth/twitter/callback, and OmniAuth gives me an auth hash full of info
4. ????
5. iOS app now has the credentials it needs to identify the user making requests when it calls my APIs
6. Authentication complete, app use proceeds as normal

It's step 4, getting the credentials back to the iOS app, that I don't know how to set up. All my APIs the iOS app calls are stateless; if they require an authenticated user, then user credentials are included in the API call. I don't know that much about writing iOS apps, and pretty much nothing about how apps interact with Safari.

What is a safe way of getting the user credentials back to the app? One that can't be snooped? If I have the callback page put information in cookies, or in the session, will that be accessible to the app but not anyone watching the traffic?

Alternately, if the app attaches some identifier for itself to the initial call to /auth/twitter, will Twitter & OmniAuth preserve that identifier so that it gets included in the /auth/twitter/callback, so that the app can then ask my back end for the credentials for an authentication that just finished associated with that identifier?

Answer (score 0):

> Alternately, if the app attaches some identifier for itself to the initial call to /auth/twitter, will Twitter & OmniAuth preserve that identifier so that it gets included in the /auth/twitter/callback, so that the app can then ask my back end for the credentials for an authentication that just finished associated with that identifier?

Did you try? Cause that's usually how your step4 goes. You keep a token or something about the user so when you get the callback you can lookup for that user again. No session or cookies, just plain db.